# Using References in methods in C++ and Returning Values?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

Imagine you are implementing a List Data Type in C++. This List of yours will keep items in a simple array and will hold instances of type: "Animal".

So for example, addItem method will be something like this:

```
void MyAnimalList::insertAnimal(Animal a){
    animalArray[currentPosition] = a;
    currentPosition++;
 }
```

So we simply have a currentPosition in the our List implementation and when we add a new Animal to it, Animal a is now referenced in the animalArray in "currentPosition" and currentPosition is then increased.

My question will be about retrieveItem. Is there any difference between these 2:

```
void MyAnimalList::getTheLastAddedAnimal(Animal &a){
    a = animalArray[currentPosition-1];
}

Animal MyAnimalList::getTheLastAddedAnimal(){
    return animalArray[currentPosition-1];
}
```

Obviously, the second method will be called like:

```
Animal lastAddedAnimal = myAnimalList.getTheLastAddedAnimal();
```

and the first one should be called like:

```
Animal someAnimal;
myAnimalList.getTheLastAddedAnimal(someAnimal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is semantic. If a method is called `getXXXXX`, you expect it to **return** that thing.

Most decent compilers implement NRVO, so efficiency isn't really an issue here. I'd go with the second version.

I would however change the definition of `insertAnimal(Animal a)` to `insertAnimal(const Animal& a)`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain ( or give a useful link ) on why you would use the const?

Comment: @KorayTugay because the method insert doesn't modify the parameter.

Comment: @KorayTugay, Using a `const Animal &` as the argument to `insertAnimal` avoids making a temporary copy of the animal as part of calling the function.

Comment: @Wyzard using a reference does that, he was asking about `const`. You're right though.

Comment: @KorayTugay, the reference is `const` to ensure that `insertAnimal` can't modify the caller's `Animal` instance.  Aside from preventing accidental modification, this makes it possible to pass a `const Animal` into the function.